# Using optim () in R to find a minimum of a two variable function

Tags: r, function, mathematical-optimization

I need to find a minimum of a two-variable function. I currently use the R function `optim()` but I have just found out that the result varies based on the trial values passed to the function. How to solve this problem? 
That is the function I refer to

---

```
optim(par, fn, gr = NULL, ...,
      method = c("Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN",
                 "Brent"),
      lower = -Inf, upper = Inf,
      control = list(), hessian = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you share the function? You problem is a typical one, you will need to run the optimisation with multiple initial guesses - the search for global optimum is a non-trivial one.